# Calling methods on objects of type id

Tags: objective-c

when I'm trying to call a method on an object of type id, i get a warning raised (method not found). Of course not, but isn't that the sense of an id object?

Is there a way to **tell the compiler:

"You don't now the class of the object on which i am calling this method, but don't worry, i'm sure it does implement it!"** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `performSelector`?

And if you've got an object type `id` it's probably a good idea to use `respondsToSelector` as well :)

i.e.

```
if ([myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(dosomething:)])
    myObject performSelector:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:@"hello"];
```

Comment: That only works if the method takes 0-2 arguments of object type.  If the method takes more than 2 arguments, or if any argument is a primitive type, that won't work.

Comment: Fine, look at NSInvocation ;)

Comment: I think this is the way to go in my situation (1 argument, many potential receiver types)!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just use a variable of the proper class type.  You can either perform an explicit cast when sending the message, or you can assign it to a variable of the correct type.  In Objective-C, the type `id` can be implicitly cast to any Objective-C object pointer type:

```
id myId = ...;

// Option 1: Use a cast when sending the message
[(MyClass *)myId someClassMethod];

// Option 2: Assign to a variable
MyClass *myObj = miId;  // Implicit cast in the assignment
[myObj someClassMethod];
```

Comment: Thanks You, finally i got what implicit casting is:)

Answer (score 1):

You could cast your `id` object to the class you know that it is.

If you have an `id` instance named `instanceA` and you know that it is of `ClassA` you cast it accordingly

```
Class A *instanceACasted = (ClassA *)instanceA;
```

then call the method

```
[instanceACasted methodCall];
```

Comment: Yeah, but it is not always the same class! Actually it is always a subclass of a ViewController, so i could cast it with ViewController. But isn't there a better way, in terms of "loose coupling"?

Comment: Then you can use if([instanceA isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]]){ // cast and call method };